# passing parameters to a matlab function from php

Tags: php, matlab

I want to call a matlab function from php using the exec command. However, how can I pass the parameters to my matlab file from php? And also how to get the results from the matlab function.

Comment: what kind of results? matrices?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameters to matlab using a call function.

You can find all the details to that [here](http://www.danpearce.co.uk/php_and_matlab).

The return data would need to be through stdout or through a temporary file. You will need to make your matlab function lay this data out nicely so you can easily parse it in php. The best way of doing depends on your datatype.